# Why does my bathroom shower have too much water pressure?

Tags: plumbing, shower, water-pressure

I have the same shower head, nothing has changed except the pressure.  It sprays so hard that it hurts, and in 10 minutes the hot water is almost gone.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to reduce pressure would be to use the water turn off valves usually located in the wall or under the floor near the shower controls. Turn both  the hot and cold shut offs back to apx half or simply turn on your shower as you would normally use it, then adjust the valves until you have a flow and pressure you like. Playing around with the hot and cold will effect the temp of the water related to your shower control settings. You may have to experiment a bit, but you can control both the max pressure and temp this way.

The other way to adjust pressure and temp on a one handle shower control is sometimes done inside the valve body. For this adjustment, you should have the installers manual. It will show you how to adjust the position of limit disks inside the valve body. These are common on newer scald resistant shower units.

Answer (score 3):

If your shower pressure suddenly increased, the cause is likely to 
be a problem with the low flow shower head flow restrictor.
Unscrew the shower head and look inside for a misaligned washer
or something else that looks out of place.
Also soak the entire shower head in vinegar for an hour or two.
This will loosen any deposits that could caused the washer to seat 
incorrectly.  Put the washer or other device back in the shower head
and place back on the shower.  This worked very well for me and
I did not have to buy a new low flow shower head.
Paul

Answer (score 1):

[image]This happened to me. ONLY the master shower was affected. The pressure got so great, the water hurt and the wind it generated blew my shower curtain around wildly. I took off the Moen shower head and cleaned it with vinegar. Inside the shower head was a tiny little o-ring not seated all the way. I nudged it back till it was fully seated. Re-installed the shower head and all fixed!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming!

Answer (score 0):

Well most new shower heads have a flow regulator to meet conservation standards.  These highly impair water flow.

If you just experience a (dramatic) increase in pressure it is very likely that you flow regulator stopped working correctly.  Maybe it broke, became unscrewed, or whatever.

To stop the flow you would need to find a replacement regulator (probably from manufacturer) or just get a new shower head.